# Python "constructor not accessible in restricted mode"

Tags: python

This has been driving me crazy, on and off, for a few months.
I'm developing an addon module for kodi (formerly xbmc), which is exclusively python.

Whenever I try to open a file, like so:

```
file = open(self.msg_bdy_props["Filename"], "r")
```

This exception is thrown:

```
IOError: file() constructor not accessible in restricted mode
```

From everything I've read, restricted mode is of a python era long past.  But there are obviously still parts of it lingering around?
I can't work around it this time, and I need to open and read files.
Any idea what might be happening and how to get around this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: It's version 2.7.9

Comment: Restricted mode is [very much in python 2.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Include/frameobject.h#L58)

Comment: Only know that error as being able to be possible to trigger when you are using Python sub interpreters via the C API and you are incorrectly sharing Python objects across interpreter contexts. Are you implementing your module as a C extension? Are you running it in a system which uses sub interpreters, such as mod_wsgi or other embedded system?

Comment: An older version of the xbmc api uses a sub interpreter with [restriction on the file module](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc-antiquated/blob/305358a0f1271251be5e4de8189c52ad51e710e3/xbmc/lib/libPython/Python/Lib/rexec.py#L151)

Comment: Thanks. That does help.  What is frustrating is that it doesn't seem to be happening 100% of the time.  I have two applications that both do similar things.  A connection to DBUS is made and use OBEX to grab items from my phone.  One of these works (PBAP), the other throws an error (MAP). Unfortunately, the obex calls have to save these objects to a file (.Get, .PullAll methods) so I am forced to have to open these files instead of being able to read the data straight into the application.  My version of Kodi is 14, it doesn't seem to have this restriction.